# UIAutomation integration bot with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-bots

did someone already find out how to create an integration bot in Xcode to start a profiling session (e.g UIAutomation test)?

I've seen the 'UI Testing in Xcode' video from WWDC this year, but they don't explain how to start a profiling integration. I hope to avoid making my Screenshot Automation test twice but then in with UI Tests.